# Are instance variables from the controller passed to the spec in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, controller

For some reason, my spec isn't passing. It appears that `@categories` isn't getting to the spec.

Here's the controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end
end
```

And my spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CategoriesController do

  describe "GET #index" do
    category = FactoryGirl.create(:category)
    subject { get :index }
    it { @categories.should include category }
  end

end
```

Error:

```
Failure/Error: @categories.should include category
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: What's the actual error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can access them using the [`assigns`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/file/README.md#assigns) spec helper:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CategoriesController do

  describe "GET #index" do
    category = FactoryGirl.create(:category)
    subject { get :index }
    it { assigns(:categories).should include category }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The instance variable is set in the controller not the spec.

If you want to ensure an instance variable is set in the controller then you should use

```
assigns(:categories).should include category
```

More information is available here:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-10/docs/controller-specs